# Meaning of "expansion bus" or "peripheral bus"

Tags: bus

From my last post https://superuser.com/questions/464608/expansion-bus-and-peripheral-bus, "expansion bus" or "peripheral bus" are said to be the same concept. **My questions here are not the same as those before. Please do read both of them, before you judge.**

1. From the Wikipedia article "[Expansion bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_bus)", expansion bus is
   defined as:

   > An expansion bus is made up of electronic pathways which move
   >   information between **the internal hardware of a computer system**
   >   (including the CPU and RAM) and **peripheral devices**. It is a collection
   >   of wires and protocols that allows for the expansion of a computer.

   As far as I know [peripheral devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral) can be internal or external to
   the computer case. So I wonder if here *peripheral devices* mean
   external peripherals only?
2. What is the opposite concept of "expansion bus" or "peripheral bus"?
3. In the following image, what buses are "expansion bus" or "peripheral bus"?

   [image]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm able to see that but as I mentioned you polish the title and you may have you luck so it may be not close. Also for more discuss you can join us [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Comment: Reopened since it's two different questions

Comment: @avirk: Thanks, your suggestion is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the Wikipedia articale about [peripheral devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral) you linked to:

> A **peripheral** is a device connected to a host computer, but not part of it. It expands the host's capabilities, but does not form part of the core computer architecture. It is often, but not always, partially or completely dependent on the host.
>
> A peripheral is generally defined as any auxiliary device such as a computer mouse, keyboard, hard drive, etc. that connects to and works with the computer in some way. Other examples of peripherals are Expansion cards, graphics cards, computer printers, image scanners, tape drives, microphones, loudspeakers, webcams, and digital cameras. RAM - random access memory - straddles the line between peripheral and primary component; it is technically a storage peripheral, but is required for every major function of a modern computer and removing the RAM will effectively disable any modern machine.

As you can see, *internal* and *external* don't refer to the computer case, but to the core computer architecture. As a rule of thumb, anything that can be removed without damaging the computer of preventing it from booting up isn't part of it's core architecture and – therefore – peripheral.

The "opposite" of an expansion bus would be an internal bus, such as those between CPU and Northbridge, Northbridge and Southbridge, CPU and chipset (all if present) or the memory bus.

Comment: internal and external do refer to the computer case. Same Wikipedia link for peripherals "Usually, the word peripheral is used to refer to a device external to the computer case, but the devices located inside the computer case are also technically peripherals. Devices that exist outside the computer case are called external peripherals, or auxiliary components.  Devices that are inside the case such as internal hard drives or CD-ROM drives are also peripherals in technical terms and are called internal peripherals, but may not be recognized as peripherals by laypeople."

Comment: I was referring to your quote. In **the internal hardware of a computer system**, *internal* refers to the core computer architecture, not the computer case.

Comment: Is the bus between northbridge and graphical card slot, called "high-speed graphical bus (AGP or PCI express)" an internal or expansion bus?

Comment: In theory, a computer system should function without a graphics card (although most desktop computers won't boot without it), so it's an expansion bus.